# How to rename multiple .RDS files in RStudio

Tags: r

I am trying to load and rename several Ggplot graphs saved as `.rds`
The below code works fine but it gives the additional suffix `.rds` to the variables that I do not need.
I would like the variables loaded in the R environment named as  `ggplot_graph1` and not `ggplot_graph1.rds`

```
Objects_Selected <- list.files(pattern = ".rds")
    
    lst1 <- lapply(Objects_Selected, function(RDS_File) {
      temp_file <- readRDS(RDS_File)
    
    })
    
    # Objects_Selected <- gsub(".rds", "", Objects_Selected)
    
    for(RDS_File in Objects_Selected){
      temp_file <- readRDS(RDS_File)
      assign(RDS_File, temp_file)
    }
```

Comment: Try `assign(gsub(RDS_File, "\.rds$", ""), temp_file)`

Comment: Sorry. I got the parameter order mixed up for `gsub`. How about `assign(gsub("\\.rds$", "", RDS_File), temp_file)`

Answer (score 0):

@MrFlick thanks a lot !
This is the correct answer:

```
Objects_Selected <- list.files(pattern = ".rds")
    
    lst1 <- lapply(Objects_Selected, function(RDS_File) {
      temp_file <- readRDS(RDS_File)
    
    })
    
    # Objects_Selected <- gsub(".rds", "", Objects_Selected)
    
    for(RDS_File in Objects_Selected){
      temp_file <- readRDS(RDS_File)
      assign(gsub("\\.rds$", "", RDS_File), temp_file)
    }
```